# Warning: Documents NO-HEAD in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create a new java project in eclipse, there is a warning saying "documents NO-HEAD" after the project name. I don't know how to solve this. Will this cause any errors in my code?

I tried to uninstall eclipse and reinstall it. However, the warning is still there.

The following image shows the warning.

[image]

Comment: My guess is your workspace is located in somewhere like `C:\Users\name\Documents\workspace` and at some point you did a `git init` in `C:\Users\name\Documents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Documents` is a *git* project without any commits. If you commit something, it will change to `[Documents master]`, or whatever branch name you use. If you don't want this to be a git project, you can delete the hidden `.git` directory in the project folder.

The message is toally harmless and not something that will affect your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find the .git file, there's another way:

1. Right click on Project
2. Team
3. Disconnect

[image: Right click on Project, Team, Disconnect]